# What's a searchable term for this bash thing: <(command)

Tags: bash

I feel extremely helpless because I can't google for it - Google simply ignores those characters (even when I put them in double quotes).

What is it called when you open a bash terminal and do:

```
diff <(command) <(cat some_file)
```

I found the answer to this some weeks ago, but now I can't remember nor find it.

Also, I remember there was some way to see what's really going on, as in it creates anonymous pipes or something. How do I go from the above command to seeing something like:

```
diff /dev/fd/53 /dev/fd/54
```

Which is what actually ends up happening. I did this a few weeks back but can't remember...

Bonus points if anyone knows how to force google to search for `<(command)` and find results specific to that rather than as if you had searched for just `command`?

Comment: are you looking for `process substitution`?

Comment: redirection - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax you've provided in your example looks like [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to me. That's the search term you want, though the link I've just provided points to the entry on this topic in the advanced bash scripting guide.

Comment: For the 2nd part of my question, I've found the answer. You can use the echo command. i.e. running `echo <(some command)` returns `/dev/fd/63` or similar.